# How can I add columns to the Accounting Batch screen?

Tags: civicontribute

I would like to modify the screen at http://mygroup.org/civicrm/batchtransaction?reset=1&bid=332

Specifically, I would like to add columns to the tables listing the transaction records.   Which CiviCRM file would I need to override?

Comment: In the link you gave, i can't see any tables or columns, could you give a screenshot instead ? By looking to the source html, you could try to find the template that was used to generate the part you want.

Answer (score 1):

You could do this by amending the profile used by the batching page? For instance on the Drupal demo site the Reserved profiles show a profile for batch contributions. So you should just add the fields to that and they'll shown on the form?